# jQuery UI dialogs and TinyMCE in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using tinyMCE and jquery-ui in the same application. The problem is, when tinyMCE is switched to fullscreen mode, it hides all the jquery-ui dialogs. Any ideas on how it is possible to keep the dialogs on top of the editor even when its in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting the zIndex property of the jQuery dialogs to 8000 and it worked :-)